# Necessary condition for improper integral of odd and even functions to converge

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

For an odd function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R $ we have $$\int_{-a}^{a} f(x) dx = 0$$ and for an even function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R $ we have $$\int_{-a}^{a} f(x) dx =2\int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx$$ 
Using these two results I'm trying to find the necessary conditions, for odd $f$ and even $f$, such that the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ converges.

For an even function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R $, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{0} f(x) dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) dx$. So, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ converges if $\int_{-\infty}^{0} f(x) dx$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ both converge. We can extend this by saying $\int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx$ has to converge as $a \rightarrow \infty$ (since $\int_{-a}^{0} f(x) dx = \int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx $ for even functions). Here I haven't used the result above directly because I know that it's not valid to say $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx=\int_{-a}^{a} f(x) dx$ as $a \rightarrow \infty$. So I'm wondering how I can use the above result directly to find the condition for te even case.

For an odd function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R $, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{0} f(x) dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) dx$. So, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ converges if $\int_{-\infty}^{0} f(x) dx$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ both converge. We can extend this by saying $\int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx$ has to converge as $a \rightarrow \infty$ (since $\int_{-a}^{0} f(x) dx = -\int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx $ for odd functions). Like for the even case, I'm not sure how I can use the earlier results directly to find the condition for the odd case.

Comment: You essentially already found out that we have convergence iff $\in_0^\infty$ converges. This applies to even and to odd functions a is the best you can get. However, for the odd case we also know that $\int_{-\inft}^\infty$ is zero if it converges

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

by definition

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f (t)dt $$  converges

$$\iff $$
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (-\infty,+\infty)}\int_x^yf (t)dt $$ exists in $\Bbb R $.

$$\lim_{a\to +\infty}\int_{-a }^axdx=0$$ but $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}xdx $$ diverges.

Comment: Very subtle, but yes, that is how it is although it took me some time to even convince my colleagues  about the second last & last line!

Comment: How can you conclude that the last one is diverge! you can see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral